# TFS API not returning results in MVC application

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a code to retrieve changesets from TFS server. The code works great in a console application. My code looks like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs....."));
tpc.Authenticate();
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

VersionSpec from = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(versionFromString, null);
VersionSpec to = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(versionToString, null);
var histories =
    vcs.QueryHistory(
        path + "/*.cs", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, from, to, Int32.MaxValue, true, true, true);


foreach (Changeset history in histories)
{
    foreach (Change change in history.Changes)
    {
         // results here....
    }
}
```

But when I move the code inside mvc application, there is no error, but it returns an empty list of histories at this line:
foreach (Changeset history in histories)

I thought it was due to insufficient privileges, so I used impersonation of a network service. 
The code is not complaining about that impersonation, but still no result at that line.

Do you think this is still a user-related issue? Should that user have specific privileges in order for it to execute and bring back results?

If I had access to that server, I would have installed processmon to see what is going on, but I don't.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got access to the server. It was related to privileges. The user I was using turned out not setup as an admin on the TFS server. I just needed to use an alternate one with administrative account.